# Oracle Query to SQL Server Query Conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

I need help converting the below query to MS SQL Server 2008 standard.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (WITH records
                AS (SELECT id,
                           start_no,
                           end_no,
                           DENSE_RANK ()
                              OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_no ASC)
                              rn
                      FROM SCOTT.SHAN_TEST3)
        SELECT id,
               start_no,
               end_no,
               rn
          FROM records
         WHERE rn = 2) a,                                      -- First record
       (WITH records
                AS (SELECT id,
                           start_no,
                           end_no,
                           DENSE_RANK ()
                              OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_no ASC)
                              rn
                      FROM SCOTT.SHAN_TEST3)
        SELECT id,
               start_no,
               end_no,
               rn
          FROM records
         WHERE rn = 1) b                                        --  2nd record
 WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.start_no < b.end_no
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of accessing table twice,also in SQL server

```
;WITH records
AS 
(
 SELECT id,start_no,end_no,
 DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_no ASC)  rn
 fROM SCOTT.SHAN_TEST3
),
a AS 
(SELECT id,start_no, end_no,rn from cte where rn=2),
b AS 
(SELECT id,start_no, end_no,rn from cte where rn=1)

SELECT 
a.id,
a.start_no,
a.end_no,
a.rn
from  a join  b
on a.id = b.id AND a.start_no < b.end_no
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the Question is incorrect or yourself, but table `a` should have `rn = 2` and table `b` should have `rn = 1` to be the same as the script posted.

Comment: cte should be replace as records, .. its working fine.